# How to fit GLMM or LMM models to analyze alpha diversity metrics (Hill numbers)?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, diversity

I am studying alpha diversity (Hill numbers) using shotgun metagenomic data. The sampling design has multiple levels of nesting, as follows: 2 years > 3 locations > 2 conditions > 1 transect > 3 replicates within the transect. My objective is to compare the individual effects of conditions and years, as well as their interaction on Hill numbers.

I tested two possibilities:

```r
m1 <- lme(response ~ condition * year,
         random = list(~1|sites, ~1|transect),
         weights = varIdent(form = ~1|condition * sites * year),
         data = hillall)


m2 <- glme(response ~ condition * year, 
     random = list(~1|sites, ~1|transect),
     method = "REML",
     weights = varIdent(form = ~1|condition * sites * year), 
     data = hillall)
```

Both models consider nesting for the transects within sites and variance structure nesting the condition, sites, and year factors. However, I'm not sure if these model specifications are correct. How can I model the random effects, considering the effect of spatial and temporal dependence, as well as the variance structure? In addition, which type of model should I use, a simple or generalized mixed effects model?

Comment: Have you considered using the `glmmTMB` package? I am pretty sure (sorry, have not actually done this) that you can have AR(1) correlation, and nested random effects, within the same formula.

Comment: Whether you should use a "simple" or "generalised" I would say depends on what your data looks like. Likely, it's theoretically more appropriate to use a distribution that is non-negative as that more correctly reflects the range that Hill numbers can take; however, if they are normal enough looking, Gaussian should be fine.

Comment: I appreciate your support, Alex. I will try this package considering your suggestions.